# Using operators give invalid value error in query

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

With the following query:

```
  const results = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  lists.findAll({
    where: {
      id: {
        [Sequelize.Op.in]: results,
      },
    },
  });
```

I am seeing the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid value { id:
   { [Symbol(in)]:
      [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] } }
```

But I don't know why my codes doesn't work...

I am on Sequelize `4.43.0` if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try without `Sequelize.Op.in`, like:

```
where: {
  id: results,
}
```

and sequelize automatically generate SQL with `in`:

.... `where id in (1,2,3)` ...